# Gulp combined task which compiles different SCSS files

Tags: css, sass, gulp, tailwind-css

I'm working on a process similar to the one described in https://nystudio107.com/blog/a-better-package-json-for-the-frontend but want to modify it to be able to compile different `SCSS` files to CSS files of the same name, e.g. `fileA.scss` compiles to `fileA.css`.

What I have at the moment works fine if I'm just working with one `SCSS` file `master.scss` compiling to `site.combined.min.css`.

From `package.json`

```
"paths": {
    "src": {
        "base": "./src/",
        "css": "",
        "img": "./src/img/",
        "js": "./src/js/",
        "scss": "./src/scss/"
    },
    "dist": {
        "base": "./public/",
        "css": "./public/assets/css/",
        "js": "./public/assets/js/",
        "fonts": "./public/assets/fonts/",
        "img": "./public/assets/img/"
    },
    "build": {
        "base": "./build/",
        "css": "./build/css/",
        "js": "./build/js/",
        "html": "./build/html/",
        "img": "./build/img/"
    },
    "tailwindcss": {
        "src": "./build/css/master.css",
        "conf": "./tailwind.config.js"
    },
    "scss": [
        {
            "src": "./src/scss/master.scss"
        }
    ],
    "templates": "./public/site/templates/"
},
"vars": {
    "siteCssName": "site.combined.min.css",
    "scssName": "master.scss",
    "cssName": "master.css"
},
"globs": {
    "distCss": [
        "./node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
        "./build/css/*.css"
    ],
    "purgecss": [
        "./html/index.html",
        "./html/site/templates/**/*.{twig}",
        "./src/js/site.js",
        "./html/assets/js/*.js"
    ],
    "purgecssWhitelist": []
},
```

And the Gulp tasks

```
gulp.task("scss", () => {
    $.fancyLog("-> Compiling scss");
    // return gulp.src(pkg.paths.src.scss + pkg.vars.scssName)
    return gulp.src(pkg.paths.src.scss + '*.scss')
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe($.sass({
                includePaths: pkg.paths.scss
            })
            .on("error", $.sass.logError))
        .pipe($.cached("sass_compile"))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer())
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write("./"))
        .pipe($.size({gzip: true, showFiles: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pkg.paths.build.css));
});

gulp.task("tailwind", () => {
    $.fancyLog("-> Compiling tailwind css");
    return gulp.src(pkg.paths.tailwindcss.src)
        .pipe($.postcss([
            $.tailwindcss(pkg.paths.tailwindcss.conf),
            require("autoprefixer"),
        ]))
        .pipe($.if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
            $.purgecss({
                extractors: [{
                    extractor: TailwindExtractor,
                    extensions: ["twig", "scss", "css", "js"]
                }],
                whitelist: pkg.globs.purgecssWhitelist,
                content: pkg.globs.purgecss
            })
        ))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pkg.paths.build.css));
});

class TailwindExtractor {
    static extract(content) {
        return content.match(/[A-z0-9-:\/]+/g);
    }
}

gulp.task("css", ["tailwind", "scss"], () => {
    $.fancyLog("-> Building css");
    return gulp.src(pkg.globs.distCss)
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe($.newer({dest: pkg.paths.dist.css + pkg.vars.siteCssName}))
        .pipe($.print())
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe($.concat(pkg.vars.siteCssName))
        .pipe($.if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
            $.cssnano({
                discardComments: {
                    removeAll: true
                },
                discardDuplicates: true,
                discardEmpty: true,
                minifyFontValues: true,
                minifySelectors: true
            })
        ))
        .pipe($.header(banner, {pkg: pkg}))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write("./"))
        .pipe($.size({gzip: true, showFiles: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pkg.paths.dist.css))
        .pipe($.filter("**/*.css"))
        .pipe($.livereload());
});
```

You can see I've replaced the 3rd line of the `scss` task so that it will deal with multiple sources and output multiple files to the `build` folder.

But what I'm getting stuck on is how does the `tailwind` task then know to use the file with the same name as used in the `scss` task and when it gets to the `css` task, how does it know not to use all the CSS files in the build folder, but only the one used in the previous tasks?

Is there a way of passing the file name to be used from one task to the next? Or should it be done a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of outputting the compiled scss into `pkg.paths.build.css`, you could output that into a different folder (ie `./build/scss/`), and set that folder as your `pkg.paths.tailwind.src`?

Alternatively, you could try setting `pkg.paths.tailwind.src` to be an array of named files, like

```
"tailwindcss": {
  "src":[pkg.paths.build.css + "fileA.css", pkg.paths.build.css + "fileB.css"],
  "conf": "./tailwind.config.js"
},
```

Either way, it will depend on how the PostCSS part of the `tailwind` task handles being passed multiple files..

Comment: Doing your second suggestion has saved a properly compiled CSS file to the build folder but when it gets to the CSS task, it's set to take all the CSS files it finds in the build folder (which also includes normalise.css which is pulled from the node_modules folder) and combine them into a single file which is specified with `dest: pkg.paths.dist.css + pkg.vars.siteCssName`. So it will now attempt to combine the main CSS file with the one for CKEditor too.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was closer than I thought. The only changes I needed to make were in the `css` task.

`return gulp.src(pkg.globs.distCss)` became `return gulp.src(pkg.paths.build.css + '**/*.css')`

`.pipe($.newer({dest: pkg.paths.dist.css + pkg.vars.siteCssName}))` became `.pipe($.newer({dest: pkg.paths.dist.css}))`

and I removed `.pipe($.concat(pkg.vars.siteCssName))` as I wasn't combining multiple CSS files anymore anyway.

This now saves a CSS file to the build folder with the same filename as the original SCSS file, and then it's compiled and saved to the dist folder, again with the same file name.